# SharePoint redirects to the site home page when I save an item with a Rich Text Field

Tags: 2013

**Update - It seems the Cisco Netscaler is causing the problem. Now I have server access (and bypassed the NLB by going direct to the WFE) then everything is working again**

**Solution - It seems Cisco Netscaler had "Intelligent Filtering" enabled which detected every HTTP POST which contained HTML in the body as a Script Injection Attack and blocked it .. *sigh***

Weird issue I am facing.

I have a SharePoint 2013 SP1 Enterprise farm running with three load balanced Web Servers (through a Cisco Netscaler). We are using Sticky Sessions (Cookie Based sessions falling back to IP based if cookies are unavailable)

The strange behaviour is that everytime I try to modify a Rich Text Field and hit "save" then I am redirected to the site home page. If I don't modify the Rich Text Field then it works fine (and I can happily edit any other properties). There is nothing in Fiddler showing except an immediate 302 redirect to "/".

This happens with both Publishing Pages as well as custom lists (which have Rich Text Fields).

- This happens with "out of the box" sites with no customisations applied
- We are using both FBA and Windows Authentication with the standard Sign-In Pages
- The error is observed with both FBA and Windows users
- This is observed in all Site Collections

We have numerous DEV / TEST boxes running the same setup, but none of them are displaying this behaviour.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**Edit** - I have since tried removing FBA (so it is Windows Auth only) and have removed two of the Web Servers (so we only have a single Web Server in the NLB). Still having exactly the same error

**Further Edit** - I have checked the ULS logs. Apart from a load of "Search not found" errors (I am not running a Search Service on this farm) there is nothing about any kind of errors. Fiddler2 just shows an immediate 302 response from the HTTPS POST event.

Comment: Cisco Netscaler intelligent filtering fail .. main question updated

Comment: Glad you got it working! Please submit your solution as an answer and mark it so as to remove this question from the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Cisco Netscaler had "Intelligent Filtering" enabled which detected every HTTP POST which contained HTML in the body as a Script Injection Attack and blocked it.

Removing this filtering resolved the problem